# Logstash and Elastic upgrade

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

I had a functional Logstash and Elasticsearch on version 5.1.

I deleted all indices, then upgraded to 6.1.

Now, when Logstash receives some event from Filebeat (Which stills version 5.1), it throws this error:

```
[2017-12-27T17:29:16,463][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Could not index event to Elasticsearch.
{
  :status => 400,
  :action => ["index", {:_id=>nil, :_index=>"logstash-2017.12.27", :_type=>"doc", :_routing=>nil}, #<LogStash::Event:0x34de85bd>],
  :response => {
    "index" => {
      "_index" => "logstash-2017.12.27",
      "_type" => "doc",
      "_id" => nil,
      "status" => 400,
      "error" => {
        "type" => "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" => "Failed to parse mapping [_default_]: [include_in_all] is not allowed for indices created on or after version 6.0.0 as [_all] is deprecated. As a replacement, you can use an [copy_to] on mapping fields to create your own catch all field.",
        "caused_by" => {
          "type" => "mapper_parsing_exception",
          "reason" => "[include_in_all] is not allowed for indices created on or after version 6.0.0 as [_all] is deprecated. As a replacement, you can use an [copy_to] on mapping fields to create your own catch all field."
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have even tried using an extremely simplistic pipeline, as you can see here:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}   

filter {
    json {
      source => "message"
    }   
}   

output {
  elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] }
}
```

Yet it throws this error over and over.

Any idea what can be wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at [changes in mapping, introduced in elasticsearch 6.0](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.x/breaking_60_mappings_changes.html)

you need to remove the `include_in_all` mapping parameter from your index template.

can you paste here your template/mapping?

Comment: Thanks a lot for this insight, it is working fine now.

I works by removing those fields or simply deleting the template and letting the new log stash creating it again.

In general, it prove me again that it is *really worthy* to read the change log for a major release.

Comment: @Navarro - How do you delete the template?

Answer (score 2):

This answer is to just expand on what @alexanderlz said. From the DevTools page in kibana I ran this:

```
GET /_template/
```

That lists all templates

here is the template we need to delete / modify (in part):

```
"logstash": {
    "order": 0,
    "version": 60001,
    "index_patterns": [
      "logstash-*"
    ],
```

So then run

```
DELETE /_template/logstash
```

once that is done restart logstash and it will reinstall a new, correct, template.

Comment: The DevTools page in kibana is very useful. This approach solved the problem for me as well. Well done!